# How to loop through variables with bash

Tags: bash

I have a script like below, and I'd like for the script to loop through variables and create a file for each variable. I have researched and can't find a way to do it. Might be that my googling is subpar.

```bash
API="link to API"

#city
newyork="latitude-longitude"
boston="latitude-longitude"
miami="latitude-longitude

curl -s "$API$city" > $city.txt
```

I have tried putting the variables in a different file and then making a loop for each line, but then the script of course included the name of the variable. Unsure of how to attack this issue without using an array.

Comment: Why exactly do you want "to attack this issue without using an array" in the first place? What's wrong with `cities=([ny]="x1" [boston]="y2" [miami]="z3")`?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with arrays, and feel that if I use it there will be more issues later on.

Comment: Well, familiar or not, it's definitely going to be easier than messing with something like [indirect variable references](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html).

Comment: @Arawelo This post has examples of what you are trying to accomplish using various methods: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459692/loop-through-variables. Consider reading in cities from a file so you don't have to edit the script every time the list changes,

Comment: `for city in "$newyork" "$boston" "$miami"; do ...; done`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Unless `ny`, `boston` and `miami` are integers, you have to use `declare -A` to get an associative array. Else they are converted to index 0.

Comment: Please, never, never... use eval

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions for input data: hash (solution by Andrey Tyukin) or file

### Hash

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

API="link to API"

# cities
declare -A CITIES_HASH=(
    ["newyork"]="latitude-longitude"
    ["boston"]="latitude-longitude"
    ["miami"]="latitude-longitude"
)

# "[@]" for all hash entries prefixed by "!" to obtains keys instead of values
for CITY in "${!CITIES_HASH[@]}"; do
    curl -s "$API${CITIES_HASH[$CITY]}" > "${CITY}.txt"
done
```

### File

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

API="link to API"

while read -r; do
    [[ -z "${REPLY}" ]] && continue
    CITY="${REPLY%%=*}"
    LAT_LONG="${REPLY#*=}"
    LAT_LONG="${LAT_LONG//\"/}"
    curl -s "$API$LAT_LONG" > "${CITY}.txt"
done <<<"$(cat latitude-longitude.txt; echo)"
```

### Alternative with `!`

```bash
echo "Alternative"
#cities
newyork="ny-latitude-longitude"
boston="bo-latitude-longitude"
miami="mi-latitude-longitude"

for CITY in newyork boston miami; do
    echo curl -s "$API${!CITY}" ">" "${CITY}.txt"
done
```

No solution is better than other. It depends about your source.
Of course, if you read files like `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab`, the second method may be the right (with adaptations).

Comment: why `<<<"$(cat latitude-longitude.txt; echo)"` vs the much simpler `<latitude-longitude.txt`?

Comment: Just for forcing a line feed at end of flow

Comment: It's unnecessary to add these `echo`, since trailing newlines are deleted in a command substitution: `Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.` [See the corresponding section in the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).