# How to use the variable name as file name instead of value?

Tags: bash

I have a script that fetches weather api then should output the data into a file, my problem is that in the last loop it outputs the results into a file that has the variable value instead of the name. Is there a way to use the variable name instead?

```
#city
tromso="lat=69.6492&lon=18.9553"
gjovik="lat=60.8941&lon=10.5001"
oslo="lat=59.9139&lon=10.7522"
trondheim="lat=63.4305&lon=10.39.51"
bergen="lat=60.3913&lon=5.3221"
echo "a"

#Creates a directory
#mkdir scraped-weather

#Loops through the cities and puts the name in
for CITY  in tromso gjovik oslo trondheim bergen; do
         echo ${CITY} > ${CITY}.txt
done
echo "b"


#I get the data for each city and puts it in the city file
for CITY in $tromso $gjovik $oslo $trondheim $bergen; do
         curl -s "$API$CITY"  |  grep -A5 -E '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'  >> ${CITY}.txt 
done
```

Comment: You can use `${!CITY}` to resolve the value so change last loop to use same list as first loop (i.e. `for CITY in tromso gjovik oslo trondheim bergen; do` ) and change to `curl -s "$API${!CITY}" .... >> ${CITY}.txt`. ( This was in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74434549/17856705) to a Q you asked a few days ago.  - see "Alternative" section.)

Comment: Hi @Gardener that unfortunately doesn't help since the script then outputs the value of the variable as a name for the file. F.ex 'lat=69.6492&lon=18.9553'.txt.

Comment: From your description, I absolutely don't know what you want to achieve. Which file should the output of the `grep` be appended to? BTW, wouldn't it be easier to make `CITY` an associative array, the keys being the city names and the values the city coordinates?

Comment: Why is this tagged with _terminal_, when you just want to discuss a _bash program_? There is nothing terminal-specific in your question.

Comment: You loop on the values of each city, instead of the names of the cities, like in your first loop.  So when you redirect the output to `${CITY}`, you are sending the output to the lat long values.  Your last loop `for` should be the same as the first one.

Comment: Are you able to share the string value for  ${API}  ?

Answer (score 0):

I located a URL I could use as substitute for your **${API}** and came up with the following adaptation of your script.

The logic does **NOT** use your variable values assigned to each city ... because these were not required for this version of the script (**obviously URL dependent**).

I also coded a few extra lines to get **additional info** from that site.

Finally, I added a loop to build a simplistic **HTML page** for local viewing the compiled extracts.

```
#!/bin/sh

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74472892/how-to-use-the-variable-name-as-file-name-instead-of-value

CITY_LIST="Ottawa Montreal Toronto Quebec Halifax Calgary Victoria"
CITY_LIST="Tromso Gjovik Oslo Trondheim Bergen"

### Generic Weather Site
#https://www.meteoprog.com/weather/Tromso/
API="https://www.meteoprog.com/weather/"

#Creates a directory
#mkdir scraped-weather

#Loops through the cities
for CITY in $(echo ${CITY_LIST})
do
    echo "\n Pulling report for ${CITY} ..."

    rm -f "${CITY}.txt"
    ### Place city name at start of file
    #echo "${CITY}" > "${CITY}.txt"

    ### I get the data for each city and puts it in the city file
    #curl -s "${API}${CITY}/"  |  grep -A5 -E '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'  >> ${CITY}.txt 
    curl -s "${API}${CITY}/" > "${CITY}_RAW.txt"

    ### Extract directly relevant segments
    tail -n +2 "${CITY}_RAW.txt"  |
    grep -A5 -E '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' >> "${CITY}.txt"

    tail -n +2 "${CITY}_RAW.txt"  |
    grep -A3 'class="feels-like"' >> "${CITY}.txt"

    tail -n +2 "${CITY}_RAW.txt"  |
    grep -A27 'class="today__atmosphere"' >> "${CITY}.txt"

    #rm -f "${CITY}_RAW.txt"
done

### Build-up HTML page for viewing locally
{
    echo "<HTML><BODY>"
    for CITY in $(echo ${CITY_LIST})
    do
        cat "${CITY}.txt"
    done
    echo "</BODY></HTML>"
} >WEATHER_REPORT.html
```

The HTML page is as follows:

```
<HTML><BODY>
        <h2>Currently in Tromso <time datetime="2022-11-27T22:25:20+01:00"><span class="city-local-time">22:25</span> - 27 November, Sunday</time></h2>
        <div class="current-temperature">
            <div class="today-temperature">
                <span dir="ltr">-3°</span>
                <div class="icons icons81x73 night moon-cloud_2" title="cloudy, clear at times, no precipitation"></div>
            </div>
        <span class="feels-like">
            Feels Like <b>-5°C</b>                        <div class="cool">Cool</div>
        </span>

        <table class="today__atmosphere">
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <th>Chance of precipitation</th>
                    <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rain-drops"></span><b>0</b> %</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Wind</th>
                                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-wind"></span><b>3</b> mps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pressure</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-meater"></span><b>753</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UV Index</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-uv"></span><b>0/12</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Humidity</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-dropp"></span><b>83</b> %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Precipitation</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rainfall"></span><b>0</b> mm</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>Currently in Gjovik <time datetime="2022-11-27T22:28:08+01:00"><span class="city-local-time">22:28</span> - 27 November, Sunday</time></h2>
        <div class="current-temperature">
            <div class="today-temperature">
                <span dir="ltr">+2°</span>
                <div class="icons icons81x73 night cloud_2-rain" title="overcast, light rain"></div>
            </div>
        <span class="feels-like">
            Feels Like <b>+2°C</b>                        <div class="cool">Cool</div>
        </span>

        <table class="today__atmosphere">
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <th>Chance of precipitation</th>
                    <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rain-drops"></span><b>60</b> %</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Wind</th>
                                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-wind"></span><b>2</b> mps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pressure</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-meater"></span><b>751</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UV Index</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-uv"></span><b>0/12</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Humidity</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-dropp"></span><b>98</b> %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Precipitation</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rainfall"></span><b>0.4</b> mm</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>Currently in Oslo <time datetime="2022-11-27T22:28:10+01:00"><span class="city-local-time">22:28</span> - 27 November, Sunday</time></h2>
        <div class="current-temperature">
            <div class="today-temperature">
                <span dir="ltr">+4°</span>
                <div class="icons icons81x73 night cloud_2" title="overcast, no significant precipitation"></div>
            </div>
        <span class="feels-like">
            Feels Like <b>+4°C</b>                        <div class="cool">Cool</div>
        </span>

        <table class="today__atmosphere">
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <th>Chance of precipitation</th>
                    <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rain-drops"></span><b>40</b> %</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Wind</th>
                                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-wind"></span><b>2</b> mps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pressure</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-meater"></span><b>757</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UV Index</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-uv"></span><b>0/12</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Humidity</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-dropp"></span><b>96</b> %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Precipitation</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rainfall"></span><b>0.07</b> mm</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>Currently in Trondheim <time datetime="2022-11-27T22:28:11+01:00"><span class="city-local-time">22:28</span> - 27 November, Sunday</time></h2>
        <div class="current-temperature">
            <div class="today-temperature">
                <span dir="ltr">+4°</span>
                <div class="icons icons81x73 night cloud_2-rain" title="overcast, light rain"></div>
            </div>
        <span class="feels-like">
            Feels Like <b>+3°C</b>                        <div class="cool">Cool</div>
        </span>

        <table class="today__atmosphere">
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <th>Chance of precipitation</th>
                    <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rain-drops"></span><b>30</b> %</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Wind</th>
                                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-wind"></span><b>3</b> mps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pressure</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-meater"></span><b>756</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UV Index</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-uv"></span><b>0/12</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Humidity</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-dropp"></span><b>80</b> %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Precipitation</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rainfall"></span><b>0.19</b> mm</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>Currently in Bergen <time datetime="2022-11-27T22:28:12+01:00"><span class="city-local-time">22:28</span> - 27 November, Sunday</time></h2>
        <div class="current-temperature">
            <div class="today-temperature">
                <span dir="ltr">+5°</span>
                <div class="icons icons81x73 night cloud_2" title="overcast, no significant precipitation"></div>
            </div>
        <span class="feels-like">
            Feels Like <b>+3°C</b>                        <div class="cool">Cool</div>
        </span>

        <table class="today__atmosphere">
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <th>Chance of precipitation</th>
                    <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rain-drops"></span><b>90</b> %</td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
                <th>Wind</th>
                                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-wind"></span><b>5</b> mps</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Pressure</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-meater"></span><b>752</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UV Index</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-uv"></span><b>0/12</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Humidity</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-dropp"></span><b>91</b> %</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Precipitation</th>
                <td class="atmosphere-spec"><span class="icon-rainfall"></span><b>0.09</b> mm</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: If you actually have bash (not some more basic shell like dash), arrays are a much better way to store lists than space-delimited strings. Also, `$(echo something)` is almost never a good idea, since the `$( )` and `echo` basically cancel each other out (except for some potentially weird parsing in between); just use the string directly.

Comment: I use #!/bin/sh (sh/dash) wherever I can and only go to bash when forced to do so.  I try to stick to the most common minimal-set shell for portability and forward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

As user1934428 suggested in a comment, an associative array would be a better way to do this. Using city names as variable names will get you into trouble with any cities with non-variable-compatible characters (e.g. Mo i Rana). You'd define the array something like this:

```
declare -A cities    # Note: need to explicitly declare associative arrays
cities=(
    [tromso]="lat=69.6492&lon=18.9553"
    [gjovik]="lat=60.8941&lon=10.5001"
    [oslo]="lat=59.9139&lon=10.7522"
    [trondheim]="lat=63.4305&lon=10.39.51"
    [bergen]="lat=60.3913&lon=5.3221"
    ["mo i rana"]="lat=66.3128&lon=14.1428"
)
```

Then, to loop over the city names, you'd use `"${!cities[@]}"`. The `!` makes it get the indexes (the city names) rather than the values the coordinates). To get the coordinates of a city, you'd use `"${cities["$city_name"]}"`. If (as in the list here) there are any cities with non-filename-friendly names, you can sanitize them before using them for filenames.

```
for city_name in "${!cities[@]}"; do
    filename="${city_name// /-}.txt"    # Convert spaces to dashes
    echo "$city_name" >"$filename"
    curl -s "$API${cities["$city_name"]}" | grep -A5 -E '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' >> "$filename"
done
```

Some other general scripting hygene recommendations: put double-quotes around all variable references (e.g. `"$city_name"` instead of just `$city_name`) to prevent weird parsing problems. Also, there are a bunch of all-caps variable names with special meanings, so to avoid conflicts it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case names for your own variables. Running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is a good way to spot common mistakes before they become problems.